# Problema de referencias con proyectos a solución

Tags: visual-studio

Tengo el siguiente problema.

Resulta que tengo un proyecto en visual studio, todo funciona bien pero hay un error en uno de los proyectos que son parte de la solución principal que no me carga bien la referencia a la misma solución.

Me explico, tengo una vista en aspx y en la parte del código tengo estas referencias:

using app_crm_erp.hipocampo.General;

donde app_crm_erp es la solución, resulta que me marca error por referencias aunque no tiene sentido puesto que este proyecto está dentro de esta solución. Lo curioso es que cuando entro al error de supuesta referencia, carga el código y carga la referencia bien, desaparece el error pero cuando vuelvo a intentar cargar la solución para debuggear me vuelve a marcar error de referencias en el mismo proyecto.

Quiero pensar que son referencias rotas o algo por el estilo pero no tengo idea de como corregirlo. Adjunto imagen del error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando entro se borra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias.